# populating alert dialog with list view,JSON

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-alertdialog

I am trying to fill an alert dialog with a JSON response how ever i am getting the following error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

i have inflated the list view in the `onCreate` as other posts suggest

i have included all relevant `xml` and `java` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".Queue.QueueStatusFragment">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listviewResp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

public class QueueStatusFragment extends Fragment{

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    private TextView txtQueue;
    private TextView txtCust;
    private TextView txtTime;
    private TextView txtBranch;
    private String urlString;
    private Button btnLeave;
    private int reasonId;
    ListView list;
    public QueueStatusFragment()
    {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_queuestatus, container, false);
       txtQueue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtQueue);
        txtTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
       txtCust = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCust);
        txtBranch = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtBranch);
        list=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listviewResp);
        btnLeave = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLeave);
        SessionV globalVariable = (SessionV) getActivity().getApplicationContext();


        urlString = "http://172.20.10.5:1012/easyQ.svc/rest/queueDetails/" + globalVariable.getCustId();
        new ProcessJson().execute(urlString);
        System.out.println("works");

        btnLeave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity()).create();

                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");

                alertDialog.setMessage("You are about to leave the queue, are you sure?");


                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        urlString = "http://172.20.10.5:1012/easyQ.svc/rest/reasons";
                        new getReasons().execute(urlString);

                        for(int i = 0; i < oslist.size();i++)
                        {
                            String id = oslist.get(i).get("id");
                            System.out.println(id);
                        }
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
               // SessionV globalVariable = (SessionV) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                //String urlString1 = "http://172.20.10.5:1012/easyQ.svc/rest/leaveQueue";
               // new JsonHandler().execute(urlString1);
                //System.out.println("works");
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    private class ProcessJson extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String stream;
            String urlString = strings[0];
            HTTPDataHandler hh = new HTTPDataHandler();
            stream = hh.GetHTTPData(urlString);
            // Return the data from specified url
            System.out.println(stream);
            return stream;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String stream) {
            if (stream != null) {
                String[] array = stream.split(",");
                String part1 = array[1];
                String part2 = array[2];
                String part3 = array[3];
                String part4 = array[4];
                String queueId = array[5];
                SessionV globalVariable = (SessionV) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                globalVariable.setQueueId(queueId);

                if (part1 != null && part2 != null && part3 != null) {
                    int minutes = (int) Integer.parseInt(part1) / 60;
                    txtBranch.append("Branch Name: " + part4);
                    txtQueue.append("Service Name: " + part3);
                    txtCust.append("Queue Position: " + part2);
                    txtTime.append("Waiting Time: " + minutes + " minutes");

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class getReasons extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String stream;
            String urlString = strings[0];
            HTTPDataHandler hh = new HTTPDataHandler();
            stream = hh.GetHTTPData(urlString);
            // Return the data from specified url
            System.out.println(stream);
            return stream;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String stream) {
            if (stream != null)
            {
               try
               {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(stream);
                    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("reasonsResult");

                   for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject reasonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                       String ID = reasonObj.getString("reason_leaving_id");
                       String reason = reasonObj.getString("description");

                       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                       map.put("description", reason);
                       map.put("id", ID);
                       oslist.add(map);
                   }

                   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                           getActivity()).create();

                   alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");

                   alertDialog.setMessage("You are about to leave the queue, are you sure?");
                   for(int i = 0; i < oslist.size(); i++)
                   {

                       ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                               R.layout.dialog_list,
                               new String[] { "description"}, new int[] {
                               R.id.text1});

                       list.setAdapter(adapter);
                       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                           @Override
                           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                   int position, long id) {
                               String branchId = oslist.get(+position).get("id");
                               final SessionV globalVariable = (SessionV) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                               globalVariable.setBranchId(branchId);


                               Fragment fragment = null;
                               fragment = new JoinFragment();
                               getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();

                           }
                       });
                   }

                   alertDialog.show();
               }
               catch(JSONException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        }
    }
    private class JsonHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String stream;
            String urlString = strings[0];
            HTTPDataHandler hh = new HTTPDataHandler();
            final SessionV globalVariable = (SessionV) getActivity().getApplicationContext();

            System.out.println("sssss" + globalVariable.getQueueId() + globalVariable.getCustId());
            JSONObject sender = new JSONObject();
            try {
                sender.put("queueid", globalVariable.getQueueId());
                sender.put("customerid", globalVariable.getCustId());
                //sender.put("reasonid",);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stream = hh.POST(urlString, sender);
            // Return the data from specified url
            System.out.println(stream);
            return stream;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String stream) {
            if (stream != null) {
                if (stream.equals("\"Successful\"")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Successfully left Queue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Fragment fragment=null;
                    fragment=new HomeFragment();
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
                } else if (stream.equals("\"Not Exist\"")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unable to leave Queue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (stream.equals("\"Not exist\"")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Not in queue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".Queue.QueueStatusFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBranch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:text="hello"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtQueue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:text="hello1"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:text="hello2"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtQueue"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtQueue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCust"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:text="hello3"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTime" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLeave"
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Leave Queue"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add `fragment_queuestatus.xml` code .

Comment: my apologies for that, i have edited the post with the code

Comment: You are inflating `fragment_queuestatus` but it lacks the `listviewResp`. That is why it returns null and you get a runtime error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286956/android-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-widget-listview-setadapt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in your `fragment_queuestatus` there is no Listview. Which you add the previous layout. That why it's not get the listview and when you try to set the adapter it's thing you set something in a NULL object. So, Add the `ListView` in the `fragment_queuestatus` layout. That will solve the problem.

Comment: thanks zahidul, this does partially solve the problem, how ever the alert  box doesn't  get populated with the list view instead the list view gets added to the fragment page

Comment: If you want to add any layout in alertdialog usr LayoutInflater to inflate the layout and get the view. So, if you inflate the listview layout and set the adapter, then you can show the list view in the alertdialog.